# Swift: How to extract image filename from an array of UIImage

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage, filenames

If I have an array of UIImage like so:

```
newImageArray = [UIImage(named:"Red.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"Green.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"Blue.png")!, UIImage(named:"Yellow.png")!]
```

How can I extract or determine the filename of an image of a certain index later on? For example:

```
println("The first image is \(newImageArray[0])")
```

Instead of returning a readable filename, it returns:

```
The first image is <UIImage: 0x7fe211d2b1a0>
```

Can I convert this output into readable text, or is there a different method of extracting filenames from UIImage arrays?

Comment: Maybe you should keep track of what name you used to create the image.

Comment: Looks like it might be the way to go. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had a look around as this has been a problem for me in the past also. UIImage does not store the filename of the image. What I did to solve the issue was instead of an image array I used a dictionary with the key as the filename and the value as the Image. In my for loop I extracted the key and value of each item into a tuple and dealt with them.

I no longer have the code but as a quick mock up of what I did see below, (I hope this fits your requirements as I know every application is different)

```
var imageDictionary = ["image1.png": UIImage(named: "image1.png"),
     "image2.png": UIImage(named: "image2.png")]
```

and then the for loop will look like:

```
for (key, value) in imageDictionary {
    println(key) // Deal with Key
    println(value) // Deal with Value
}
```

...as I say this worked for me and the scenario I needed it for, I hope you can use it also!

Good luck!

Comment: That would be a really neat way to do it. So what would be the syntax to then check if an index is a specific filename (key)?

Comment: var index = imageDictionary.indexForKey("Key")

Comment: No probs, swift dictionary has all kinds of methods. Hopefully one will suit.

Answer (score 1):

Once you create the instance of the `UIImage`, all references to the name are lost. For example, when you make an image from a file, you do something like this:

```
var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "image.png")
```

After that's done, there are no more references to the file name. All of the data is stored in the `UIImage` instance, regardless of where it came from. As the comments said above, you'll need to devise a way to store the names if you must do so.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation on that. I'll have to do some extra coding before creating the array.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to start with an array of the names (since you can't go back to the names from the images easily):

```
let imageNames = [ "Red.png", "Green.png", "Blue.png", "Yellow.png"]
```

Then you can create an array of the images using:

```
let images = imageNames.map { UIImage(named: $0) }
```

Comment: You forgot to unwrap the optional returned by UIImage(named:$0)!

Comment: Actually, I didn't forget, it was a conscious choice :)  Either way works, but I'm really not a fan of hard unwrapping optionals and this lets you handle it in a more user friendly manner.

Answer (score 0):

Its a really tricky one. I finally managed to get it to work within a Table View Controller. ( Swift 2.1, Xcode 7)

My Image names were as below in the 'icons' array with .png extension.
I created an array for the image names.

```
        var icons = ["BirthdaysImage", "AppointmentsImage", "GroceriesImage","MiscellaneousImage"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("iconsReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

   //image display
            iconName = icons[indexPath.row]
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: iconName)

            return cell
        }

     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   //find out which IMAGE got selected
            var imageSelected = icons[indexPath.row]
            print(imageSelected)

        }
```