# How do I replace a changing array with another value?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a date array which contains the current day plus 10 days, and I am importing an array from a database. I also have an animal name array. Based on what is imported I want to place the animal name in a filtered array in a filtered array. For example:

```
  date array: `[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]`
  imported date array from db: [9, 12, 14, 18]
  imported animal name array from db: [dog, cat, tiger, sheep]
```

This is what I want the filtered animal name to look like

```
filtered animal name array: [dog, "", "", cat, "", tiger, "", "", "", sheep]
```

I know the code I provided is wrong, I feel I am approaching this incorretly. How should I do this?

```
 for(var j = 0; j < self.arrayofweek.count; j++){
                        for(var t = 0; t < self.datesfromdb.count; t++){
                            if(self.date[t] == self.datearray[j]){
                                self.namefiltered[t] = self.tutorname[j]
                                 print("filtered name \(self.namefiltered)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data:

```
let dates = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
let imported = [9, 12, 14, 18]
let animals = ["dog", "cat", "tiger", "sheep"]
```

Reworked:

```
let filtered = dates.map { zip(imported, animals).map { $0.0 }.indexOf($0).map { animals[$0] } ?? "" }
```

Output:

```
print(array) // ["dog", "", "", "cat", "", "tiger", "", "", "", "sheep"]
```

Based on FranMowinckel's answer, but 100% safe.

Comment: What about the coalescing operator: `dict[$0] ?? ""`. BTW +1 for the `zip` function, I didn't now that one.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of using it. I'm sure it can be even shorter. It'd be nice to create the dictionary in one line, but using `reduce` to create arrays or dictionaries will decrease the performance too much.

Comment: What if I want to do the same with a UIImage array?

Comment: Let me take a look, tbh I haven't used `UIImage` much before. I assume the animals array would be an array of `UIImage`?

Comment: According to other SO posts, the filename of the image is lost after the `UIImage` is created. You'll have to save the name somewhere else to keep track of it. You could use a dictionary like it's explained in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113598/swift-how-to-extract-image-filename-from-an-array-of-uiimage

Comment: The images are being imported from parse

Answer (score 3):

I tried this in a playground. What it does it iterates over each `Int` in your `date array`. It then tries to find that same `Int` in the `date array db`. If it can find it then it tries to take the index and lookup in the `animal array`. I updated some variable names so you'll need to translate them.

```
let date = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
let foundDates = [9, 12, 14, 18]
let animals = ["dog", "cat", "tiger", "sheep"]

var filteredAnimals = [String]()
for currentDate in date {
    // Look up the date  in the foundDates array
    // If it's found, ensure that index is in bounds of the animal array
    if let index = foundDates.indexOf(currentDate) where (0..<animals.count).contains(index) {
        filteredAnimals.append(animals[index])
    } else {
        filteredAnimals.append("")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit, even shorter:

```
dates.map { datesDb.indexOf($0).map { animalsDb[$0] } ?? "" }
```

Just use a map function (this doesn't create any auxiliary array or dictionary):

```
var dates = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
var datesDb = [9, 12, 14, 18]
var animalsDb = ["dog", "cat", "tiger", "sheep"]

let result = dates.map { date -> String in
  if let index = datesDb.indexOf(date) where index < animalsDb.count {
    return animalsDb[index]
  } else {
    return ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Your short version is a nice touch ;) The only downside of this is, it's not completely safe. If `datesDb` has more matching dates than the count of `animalsDb`, it will crash.